# Run a Sql Query on multiple Servers and each server has different databases(database name is diff on each server) with same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Run a Sql Server Query on multiple Servers and each server has different databases(database name is diff on each server) with same tables

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/executing-a-set-of-sql-script-files-sql-on-a-group-of-sql-server-databases

Comment: @Avitus - My question is I have sql query which should be executed on multiple servers having multiple databases. Each database on multiple servers have same set of tables.

Comment: @Puskar: are you asking if it's possible? Or how to do it? What's the query? In what context is this running? What have you tried? Your question is currently very unclear and is likely to be closed as such if additional details are not edited in.

Comment: @Avitus - I am asking how it can be done ? I have tried central server management.

Comment: Can someone provide me the solution ?

Comment: Let me provide an answer in line with your question: You log into each server in SSMS and run your query. Now you need to explain if/why this doesn't suit your requirements. Does the data go somewhere? Do you have a dataset somewhere which maps the server to the database name?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid..Hey I have to run a job, basically need to prepare a report and cannot login on to all the servers one by one and each DB under those servers.. I have fifteen servers and 126 DBs.

Answer (score 0):

In the management studio, you can register multiple servers into one group. Then you can run query on the group.

Comment: Hey, I think you are talking about central management server. there the problem is query is running in all the DBs of a particular server. I want only selective DBs from each server.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS open Registered Servers and create a New Server Group under Local Server Groups.

Under this group create New Server Registration for each server you wish to query. If the DB names are different ensure to set a default for each in the properties. You can register a server/instance multiple times with different default DBs.

Now go back to the Group you created in the first step, right click and select New Query. A new query window will open and any query you run will be executed on each server in the group. The results are presented in a single data set with an extra column name indicating which server the record came from. If you use the status bar you will note the server name is replaced with multiple.